# How to change the name "References" in IEEEtran to "Bibliography"

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, naming

I am using the `ieeetran` class. In the Bibliography, the title is "References". Does anyone know how to change the title to "Bibliography"?

Comment: When using the default [`ieeetran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) document class, the `thebibliography` environment prints as References (what you expect/want). So you must be doing something different, or using a different class option, or maybe using a package that interferes with this. Could you please produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current setup. Something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As Werner stated, using `IEEEtran`,the default is `References`, in small caps font, at least with `\usepackage{biblatex}`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\def\refname{Bibliography}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Does not work in my case. The heading is still "References" after adding this.

Comment: This worked for me if I put it after `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, or just before `\bibliography{...}`

Answer (score 0):

`\def\refname{Bibliography}` does not work for me when used with IEEE tran class. Although below command was useful:

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
```